# Open Zoom meeting email link (URL) on iPad Air

Tags: ipad, ipados, zoom.app

I am not a regular iPad user. On Windows I can open a Zoom meeting directly from the link I receive with the invitation email. I just click on that link, the Browser opens and Zoom starts connected with that meeting.

How do I accomplish the same on an iPad? What happened in my case was that the Zoom App opened, but was NOT connected to that particular meeting. I had to manually copy/paste the id/password parts to get connected.

How can I directly open a Zoom meeting from the invitation email on iPad?

Comment: The zoom tag is more for Accessability than the zoom.app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom steers iOS meeting very strongly to download the native app by default.

You will have significantly less friction and more features and control if you install the app.

That being said, [zoom does not support Safari or Mobile Safari for their web client](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360027397692-Desktop-client-mobile-app-and-web-client-comparison) but you may be able to find several links to click and tap to see if you can coax a web meeting to happen.

- https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/214629443-Quick-start-guide-for-the-Zoom-web-client

The person sending the meeting can force you to see the client install link first, be careful: look for fine print or links as you follow the “onboard links” and avoid clicking the super large install client link and button.

- https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115005666383-Show-a-Join-from-your-browser-Link

If you don’t use one of the recommended browsers on your iPad, consider asking mobile safari to **Request Desktop Website** when you activate a zoom invite link / landing page.

[image: Request Desktop Website]